# Размеры блоков [Flexbox]

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Есть код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  transform: translate(25%, 25%);
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.image-src {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530707114297-4af4b3cafe16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80" class="image-src">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1 class="title">Some title</h1>
    <p class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: Почему картинка шириной не 50px как задано?
Если задавать блоку `.image` `min-width` всё работает как нужно.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  transform: translate(25%, 25%);
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.image {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.image-src {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530707114297-4af4b3cafe16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80" alt="Image" class="image-src">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1 class="title">Some title</h1>
    <p class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как избавится от этого, подозреваю что это из-за flex. Если нет - то почему ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите значение flex-shrink: 0 для image и flex-shrink: 1 для текста.

Comment: Спасибо, решил вопрос